# LINQ (aggregate) query to add multiple arrays together based on criteria

Tags: vb.net, linq, aggregate

I have a data table with time-series data. How do I write a query to add daily data together for selected series?

My table looks like this...

- Day,Y,Series
- 1,1,A
- 1,2,A
- 1,3,A
- 2,2,A
- 2,3,B
- 2,5,C
- 3,4,A
- 3,1,B
- 3,4,C
- etc.

I want to return an array (dY) based on a list e.g. {"A","C"}. e.g. giving the Y value (for A+C) for each day...
dY = {4,7,8}

I have managed to write the query in SQL

```sql
SELECT Sum(myTable.Y) AS [Total Of Y]

FROM AAAA

WHERE (((myTable.Series) In (1,3)))

GROUP BY myTable.X;
```

and I think it should be something like this in LINQ (VB.NET)

```
Dim mySeries = {1, 3}

Dim Ys = (From myrows In oSubData Where mySeries.Contains(myrows("Series")) Select mycol = Sum(Val(myrows("Y"))))
```

Comment: Short of asking someone to do this coding for you, there's not really a question here. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I manged to do it in SQL

Comment: SELECT mytable.X, Sum(mytable.Y) AS [Total Of Y]
FROM AAAA
WHERE (((mytable.Series) In (1,3)))
GROUP BY mytable.X;